# My Label Box always outputs "Too Low" even when user input changes

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have recently started using Xamarin for my college course and cannot figure out how to fix my if-else statement, since it always displays "Too Low" even when I change my user value. Even when the field is empty it will always display the "Too Low" text. I even added the random number into the text field to see if the number matched if it would display differently but even with the matching numbers, same result. Any help would be appreciated.

**MainPage.Xaml Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
             x:Class="GuessGame.MainPage">

    <StackLayout x:Name="ActualContent">
        <!-- Application Title -->
        <Frame BackgroundColor="Black" Padding="24" CornerRadius="0">
            <Label Text="The Number Guessing Game"  HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White" FontSize="36"/>
        </Frame>

        <!-- User Guess-->
        <StackLayout x:Name="SLUserGuess" Orientation="Horizontal" 
                     HorizontalOptions="Center">
            <Label Text="My number is between 1-20, can you guess?:  " />
            <Entry x:Name="EntryGuess" Placeholder="Guess" Keyboard="Numeric"/>
        </StackLayout>

        <Button x:Name="BtnGuess" Text="Guess"
                HorizontalOptions="Center" BorderColor="DarkGreen" BorderWidth="3"  
                Clicked="BtnGuessGame_Clicked"/>

        <Label x:Name="LblGuess" Text="" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

**MainPage.Xaml.cs Code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace GuessGame
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
       
        //private int lives = 7;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //Random Number Method
        private int RandomNumber()
        {
            //Random Number Generator
            Random rdm = new Random();
            int random = rdm.Next(1, 20);

            return random;
        }

        // Compare Numbers Method (FIX: Always displays Too Low)
        private void CompareNumber(int userNum)
        {
            int randNo = RandomNumber();

            if(userNum > randNo)
            {
                LblGuess.Text = "Too high: " +randNo;
            }
           else if(userNum < randNo)
            {
                LblGuess.Text = "Too low: " +randNo;
            }
           else if(userNum == randNo)
            {
                LblGuess.Text = "Correct: " +randNo;
            }
        }
        
        private void BtnGuessGame_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Need to check if user entered data
            // bool isGuessEmpty;

            //Testing String
            //isGuessEmpty = string.IsNullOrEmpty(EntryGuess.Text);

            //Testing the boolean
            // if(isGuessEmpty)
            // {
            // return;
            // }

            int userNum = 0;
            CompareNumber(userNum);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can always put a break point there and debug, it seems you are assigning userNum 0 value and comparing it with a random number i interval[1, 19], thus condition userNum < randNo will always be true

Comment: x:Name="EntryGuess" where do you reference this name?

Comment: CompareNumber(EntryGuess);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are always passing 0 into `CompareNumber`

```
int userNum = 0;
CompareNumber(userNum);
```

0 will **always** be less than `Rand(1,20)`

instead, try this

```
// you should add checks to validate that EntryGuess is not null
// and is a valid integer value using int.TryParse()
int userNum = int.Parse(EntryGuess.Text);
CompareNumber(userNum);
```